# How to regenerate code to instantiate object from instance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, reflection, code-generation

For unit testing, I would like to generate the minimum of swift code that is needed in order to re-create an instance.

For example, I've got the following struct:

```swift
struct User {
    enum Role {
        case admin, marketing, tester, developer, sales
    }

    let name: String
    let email: String

    let icon: URL?
    let roles: [Role]

    public init(name: String, email: String, icon: URL? = nil, roles: [Role]? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.icon = icon
        self.roles = roles
    }
}
```

And at runtime I've got this user, created from various sources:

```
▿ User
  - name: "John Appleseed"
  - email: "john@example.com"
  - icon: nil
  ▿ roles: Optional([User.Role.admin])
    ▿ some: 1 element
      - User.Role.admin
```

I would like to generate the swift code that I need to re-create this user in a unit test.

Reflection gives me a good start, but it's not ideal:

```swift
print(String(reflecting: user))
```

Result:

```swift
MyLibrary.User(name: "John Appleseed", email: "john@example.com", icon: nil, roles: Optional([MyLibrary.User.Role.admin]))
```

It's not ideal because:

- All types prefixed by their module
- Explicit optionals
- Included nil properties
- No pretty formatting with indentation

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```swift
User(
    name: "John Appleseed",
    email: "john@example.com",
    roles: [.admin]
)
```

I could conform my types to `CustomReflectable` to improve the optionals and `nil`'s:

```
extension User: CustomReflectable {
    public var customMirror: Mirror {
        var children: [(label: String?, Any)] = [
            ("name", name as Any),
            ("email", email as Any)
        ]

        if let icon {
            children.append(("icon", icon))
        }

        if let roles, !roles.isEmpty {
            children.append(("roles", roles))
        }

        return Mirror(
            self,
            children: children,
            displayStyle: .struct
        )
    }
}
```

And perhaps string replace the lib name?

```
let result = String(reflecting: user).replacingOccurrences(of: "MyLibrary.", with: "")
print(result)
```

Result:

```
User(name: "John Appleseed", email: "john@example.com", roles: [User.Role.admin])
```

This already improves it a lot but the enum value still has a lengthy type, and the code has no indentation.

Also having to conform all the types to `CustomReflectable` and maintain it would be quite some work.

Any tips on how to improve this?

Comment: So you are trying to generate Swift code at *runtime*? What good is that if you can't compile/run it? If you just want a copy of a `struct`, just assign it to another variable - that makes a copy. Or you can implement `Codable`.

Comment: There's no built in way to do this, so you'll either need to find a library for it, or implemented yourself. I'm curious though, what are you trying to use this for?

Comment: Yes I want it at runtime when the app is running, to print it out on the console, or write it out to a file. In both cases the developer can then copy paste the resulting swift code into a unit test (different target) to recreate this specific instance for a unit test. During the unit tests it's not possible to obtain this instance directly.

Comment: According your last comment, you need a function that takes an instance  of User and  returns a string which represents Swift code, which itself creates the instance again when copy-pasted into a Swift source file?  Not sure if I understood it correctly, but this above seems easy to accomplish with an extension function. Then, as an example, use a breakpoint where you halt the program when the user value is available, then call the function and have fun with the output.

Comment: Yes that is what I want, but I would rather not write all those extensions by hand.